# How do I traverse a tree in Scheme?

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, b-tree

I'm new to scheme and I am trying to learn how to traverse a B-tree. I'm limited to certain commands from the language which is making this even more complicated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(define tree'("R" 100 999
(
 ("R" 100 199
      (
       ("L" 120 140 160 180)
      )
  )

 ("R" 200 299
      (
       ("L" 220 240 260 280)
       )
  )
 )))

(define (treeTraversal a)
  (if(equal? (null? a) #t) 0
  (cdr (treeTraversal (cdr a)))))

(treeTraversal tree)
```

When I run it via debugger it shows that it is going down the list first clipping that first "R" off then 100, then 999, but from there the list goes null and show's "()" in the debugger. After that I get the error:

> mcdr: contract violation
>   expected: mpair?
>   given: 0

I understand that it is returning 0 because the function sees an empty list now but I don't understand why the list goes null instead of continuing to read into the nested list.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated. This is my first time posting a question so please be patient with me :)

Comment: `(equal? (null? a) #t)` is in fact `(null? a)`, as `null?` returns a boolean value.

Comment: Good point but I'm still unable to get past the first three items in the list. I still get the same error too.

Comment: @tjorchrt I understand what you're saying about the b-tree and I am aware. Guess I should've put that in the term in quotes because I'm not really focused on the construction of the tree or it even being a b-tree. This work is focused on the concept of recursion and using it to find a certain value in one of the leaves in the tree. My professor gave us this tree as an example of how the trees would be made with list within a list. So although your suggestion to search for b-tree would further explain what I've learned about them, I'm not sure if it would really help with my problem. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (treeTraversal a)
  (if (null? a)
      #!null
      (if (pair? a)
          (cons (treeTraversal (car a))
                (treeTraversal (cdr a)))
          a)))
```

will traverse and duplicate your tree.